# Implementation of the majority merge algorithm for finding a super-sequence from sub-sequences?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, compression, bioinformatics

I've got a small set of sequences of unique values that I want to combine into a single super-sequence where the relative order of each value is maintained, to the extent possible.  For instance (quotes around strings ignored for simplicity):

```
list1 = [Mary, Bob, Sue, Roger]
list2 = [Bob, Alice, Sue, Dave]
list3 = [Mary, Bob, Larry, Sue, Roger]

superSequence = [Mary, Bob, Alice, Larry, Sue, Roger, Dave]
```

The goal is to generate an object from which the original lists can be recreated, such as:

```
obj = {
    Mary: [1, 3],
    Bob: [1, 2, 3],
    Alice: [2],
    Larry: [3],
    Sue: [1, 2, 3],
    Roger: [1, 3],
    Dave: [2]
}
```

Ignoring for the moment that object key order isn't guaranteed in all cases, one could iterate over these keys and use the indices in each associated array to regenerate the original lists.  Because the super-sequence is represented as a JS object, the values in it must be unique.

Clearly, not every set of sequences can be combined in this way:

```
list1 = [Mary, Bob, Sue]
list2 = [Bob, Mary, Sue]

superSequence = [Mary, Bob, Sue] OR
superSequence = [Bob, Mary, Sue]
```

Picking one or the other should be fine in most cases, with bonus points for an algorithm that can highlight where the order was indeterminate.

In researching this, I seem to have stumbled upon an NP-hard problem that's well-studied in compression, bioinformatics, and other fields.  There's something called a majority merge algorithm that seems to be a reasonably decent approximation for this problem, but my ability to translate academic paper [pseudo-code](http://www.statistica.unimib.it/%7Edellavedova/papers/sac2001.pdf) into something usable has atrophied over the years.  So I was hoping to find an actual implementation in JS, or C, or Python or something that doesn't rely on magic libraries.

Comment: Small correction - In obj {} I think it should read Bob:  [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some further thought, I realized there is a much simpler answer to your question. Since we can assume the same name does not occur multiple times in a given list this will work:

```
var simpleCombine = function (arr1, arr2) {
    "use strict";
    arr1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
    arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));
    var i, j, arrOut = [];
    while (arr1.length) {
        var val = arr1.shift(), found = false;
        for (j = 0; j < arr2.length; j += 1) {
            if (val === arr2[j]) {
                //If we wound an overlap then put everything to the left of it 
                // in arr2 into the final array
                found = true;
                var pos = arrOut.length;
                arrOut.push(val);
                var newVals = arr2.splice(0, j);
                while (newVals.length) {
                    arrOut.splice(pos, 0, newVals.pop());
                }
                arr2.shift(); //get rid of dup
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
             //No overlap found, just add it to the out array
            arrOut.push(val);
        }
    }
    //anything left in arr2? Add it to out array
    arrOut = arrOut.concat(arr2);

    //check for duplicates based on user requirement of each item in the 
    // sequence only occurs once. 

    for (i = 0; i < arrOut.length; i += 1) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < arrOut.length; j += 1) {
            if (arrOut[i] === arrOut[j]) {
                //If we find an overlap warn the user, and remove the dup.
                console.warn('Even with strict ordering, multiple solutions are possible');
                arrOut.splice(i,1);
                i -= 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return arrOut;
};

var findMultipleSCS = function (arr) {
    var first = arr.shift();
    while (arr.length) {
        first = simpleCombine(first, arr.shift());
    }
    return first;
};

list1 = ["Mary", "Bob", "Sue", "Roger"];
list2 = ["Bob", "Alice", "Sue", "Dave"];
list3 = ["Mary", "Bob", "Larry", "Sue", "Roger"];

console.log(findMultipleSCS([list1, list2, list3]));
```

My original answer is below because it is more accurate for lists that may contain the same name multiple times.

```
//This code works for things where the important thing is that order is
//maintained, not that each entry only occurs once
var findSCS = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var lcsLen, lcsBack, combine;
    lcsLen = function(arr1, arr2) {
        //This function moves through the arrays developing the 
        // length of the longest possible sequence of identical order.
        var dists = [[0]], i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i += 1) {
            dists[i + 1] = [];
            for (j = 0; j < arr2.length; j += 1) {
                dists[i + 1][0] = 0; // initialize 0'th column/row with 0
                dists[0][j + 1] = 0; // this could be done in a separate loop
                dists[i + 1][j + 1] = dists[i + 1][j + 1] || 0; // initialize i,j
                if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
                    //if this condition is met then we have a longer overlap
                    dists[i + 1][j + 1] = dists[i][j] + 1;
                } else {
                    //if not take the max length so far
                    dists[i + 1][j + 1] = Math.max(dists[i][j + 1], dists[i + 1][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return dists;
    };

    lcsBack = function (dists, x, y, i, j) {
        //this recursive function takes the longest possible array and build
        // the actual list starting from the bottom right of the matrix
        // created by lcsLen
        if (!i || !j) {
            return [];
        } else if(x[i - 1] === y[j - 1]) {
            return lcsBack(dists, x, y, i - 1, j - 1).concat([x[i - 1]]);
        } else {
            if (dists[i][j-1] > dists[i-1][j]) {
                return lcsBack(dists, x, y, i, j-1);
            } else {
                return lcsBack(dists,x,y,i-1,j);
            }
        }
    };

    combine = function (lcs, arr1, arr2) {
        //this take the lcs and fills in the non-overlapping part of 
        // the original lists, creating the scs
        var out = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
        var i, testing = 0, outPos = 0, positions = [0];
        for (i = 0; i < arr1.length && testing < lcs.length; i += 1) {
            if (lcs[testing] === arr1[i]) {
                positions[testing + 1] = i;
                testing += 1;
            }
        }
        testing = 0; outPos = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i += 1) {
            if (lcs[testing] === undefined || lcs[testing] !== arr2[i]) {
                out.splice(positions[testing] + outPos, 0, arr2[i]);
                outPos += 1;
            } else {
                testing += 1;
                outPos += 1;
            }
        }

        return out;
    };

    return function (arr1, arr2) {
        //get the length matrix to determine the maximum sequence overlap
        var lcsLenMat = lcsLen(arr1,arr2);
        //Take that distance matrix and build the actual sequence (recursively)
        var lcs = lcsBack(lcsLenMat, arr1, arr2, arr1.length, arr2.length);
        //Build the SCS
        var tempScs =  combine(lcs, arr1, arr2);
        //This code will allow for duplicates, and in your second example
        // It will generate a list with two bobs, which is arguably more
        // correct for general purpose use.
        return tempScs;
}());

var findMultipleSCS = function (arr) {
    var first = arr.shift();
    while (arr.length) {
        first = findSCS(first, arr.shift());
    }
    return first;
};

list1 = ["Mary", "Bob", "Sue", "Roger"];
list2 = ["Bob", "Alice", "Sue", "Dave"];
list3 = ["Mary", "Bob", "Larry", "Sue", "Roger"];

console.log(findMultipleSCS([list1, list2, list3]));
```

Most of these ideas where taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem

The order you put these in will determine which non unique solution you get. For instance list1, list2, list3 give you your first answer, however list2, list3, list1 gives you the also correct:

```
["Mary", "Bob", "Larry", "Alice", "Sue", "Dave", "Roger"]
```

If you want to maintain the priority order than list1, list2, list3 does have a unique solution and this will alert you of a duplicate possibility with a console.warn looking for duplicates.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like a great start.  Is there a particular reason the code is turning the arrays into strings and then back into arrays?  (At least, I think that's what it's doing.  Still  stepping through it.)

Comment: @jdunning I fixed what you mentioned, I just had not out of laziness. Also I found a much more efficient algorithm if we can assume each list will only contain each name once. The original algorithm now creates the super list of [Bob, Mary, Bob, Sue] with your second example. This is because it allows for one name to occur multiple times in each list and in between lists, focusing more on maintaining perfect order.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @aduss! When I call the new function with ["Mary", "Bob", "Sue"] and ["Bob", "Mary", "Sue"], I get this output: "Even with strict ordering, multiple solutions are possible. [ 'Mary', 'Bob', 'Sue' ]". Which is actually what I want anyway, because each string can only appear once as a key in the output object.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in the simpleCombine() function where the newVals get inserted into arrOut in reverse order.  Since they're being added to the end of arrOut, it would be simpler to just concat the whole newVals array.

Comment: @jdunning Could you give the updated function a try? I switched newVals from shift to pop, should fix the bug?

Answer (score 2):

Building on the `simpleCombine()` function from aduss I came up with a solution that seems to work pretty well.  It doesn't currently flag that duplicate items in the result are getting deleted, but that could be implemented with some additional logic in the final `filter()` call.

```js
function combineLists(...lists)
{
    var superSequence = lists.slice(1).reduce((list1, list2) => {
        var result = [];

            // we need to make a copy of list2 since we mutate it in the loop below
        list2 = [].concat(list2);

        list1.forEach(item => {
            var overlapIndex = list2.indexOf(item);

            if (overlapIndex > -1) {
                    // add 1 to overlapIndex so we also splice out the matching item
                result = result.concat(list2.splice(0, overlapIndex + 1));
            } else {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });

            // anything remaining in list2 is by definition not in list1, so add
            // those items to the result
        return result.concat(list2);
    }, lists[0]);

        // look back at the list up to the current item and then filter it out if
        // there's a duplicate found.  this keeps the first instance of each item.
    return superSequence.filter((item, i, list) => list.slice(0, i).indexOf(item) == -1);
}

var list1 = ["Mary", "Bob", "Sue", "Roger"],
    list2 = ["Bob", "Alice", "Jimmy", "Chuck", "Sue", "Dave"],
    list3 = ["Mary", "Bob", "Larry", "Sue", "Roger"];

console.log(combineLists(list1, list2, list3).join(" "));
```

Comment: I upvoted this, it is much more elegant than my solution. Well done.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  In the actual application I needed this for, your algorithm is working very well.  I'm not seeing anything mis-ordered in the sub-sequences when they're recreated from the order specified by the super-sequence.